# How to let TS know about type check inside of a getter in class?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a Tree class:

```
class Tree {
    data: string | string[]

    public get is_leaf() {
        return typeof this.data === 'string'
    }

    someMethod() {
        if (this.is_leaf) {
            // do something
        } else {
            this.data.push('Something')
        }
    }
}
```

Data could be a string or an array of string (just for example), and, depends on the current type, I will have some conditions in its methods. Unfortunately, TS knows nothing about what's inside of the getter:
[image]

But if I move type check inside of an `if` like this:

```
    someMethod() {
        if (typeof this.data === 'string') {
            // do something
        } else {
            this.data.push('Something')
        }
    }
```

everything will be fine.

Can it be solved somehow?

Comment: Make it an actual [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), right now that method just returns `boolean`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type predicates in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58125860/type-predicates-in-typescript)

Comment: @jonrsharpe will try it!

Comment: Well, this predicates are not applicable for class getters :( It was so close

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
class Tree {
    data: string | string[];

    public get is_leaf() {
        return typeof this.data === 'string';
    }

    someMethod() {
        if (this.is_leaf) {
            // do something
        } else {
            (this.data as string[]).push('Something');
        }
    }
}
```

You have to specify what type data is: string or string[]